# CopyToClipboard - Crashes at copy line

Tags: c#, mono, crash, clipboard

I'm on my Mac, I'm coding in MonoDevelop and my console application crashes at the Clipboard.SetText line. This is the code:

http://pastebin.com/LwV7sQhG

Comment: OK, would it be too much to ask to implement some basic logging to see if there's an exception getting thrown? What kind of inputs are you giving it when it throws this exception? Have you attempted to debug this at all?

Comment: I have, I found the error was at " System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText (all); " Also the program doesn't state any errors, it just crashes for no reason :(

Comment: Yeah, programs don't crash for no reason. There's a reason and probably an exception. You need to put a try/catch around that line and log any exceptions that might be getting generated.

Comment: And how exactly am I supposed to do that? ^-^

Comment: Google? Use [Try-catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw(v=vs.90).aspx) around `SetText` and write any exceptions generated to a text file. Can you not step through this code?